# source inject and program crash

Tags: c

Today, I read an article (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx) to describe source inject, and I try to write a program to do the same thing. But I inject source to winmind and it crashes. I can not find crash reason.

My code:

1.describe inject data struct

`typedef LRESULT (WINAPI *MESSAGEBOX)(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT);`

```
typedef struct {
HWND hwnd;
    UINT type;
    MESSAGEBOX fnMessageBox;            // pointer to user32!SendMessage
    BYTE pbText[64 * sizeof(TCHAR)];    // text param
    BYTE pbTextCap[64 * sizeof(TCHAR)]; // caption param
} INJDATA, *PINJDATA;
```

2.the code being injected

```
static int WINAPI ThreadFunc (INJDATA *pData)
{
    int nXferred = 0;

    nXferred = pData->fnMessageBox( pData->hwnd, (LPCWSTR)pData->pbText, (LPCWSTR)pData->pbTextCap, pData->type );
    pData->pbText [63 * sizeof(TCHAR)] = __TEXT('\0');
    pData->pbTextCap [63 * sizeof(TCHAR)] = __TEXT('\0');       

    return nXferred;
}


// This function marks the memory address after ThreadFunc.
// int cbCodeSize = (PBYTE) AfterThreadFunc - (PBYTE) ThreadFunc.
static void AfterThreadFunc (void) {
}
```

3.Copies ThreadFunc and INJDATA to the remote process, and starts the excecution of the remote ThreadFunc

```
int CallMessageBox (HANDLE hProcess, HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR pbString, LPCWSTR pbStringCap)
{   
    HINSTANCE   hUser32;
    INJDATA     *pDataRemote;   // the address (in the remote process) where INJDATA will be copied to;
    DWORD       *pCodeRemote;   // the address (in the remote process) where ThreadFunc will be copied to;
    HANDLE      hThread = NULL; // the handle to the thread executing the remote copy of ThreadFunc;
    DWORD       dwThreadId = 0;

    int       nCharsXferred = 0; // number of chars retrieved by WM_GETTEXT in the remote thread;
    DWORD dwNumBytesXferred = 0; // number of bytes written/read to/from the remote process;

    __try {
        hUser32 = GetModuleHandle(__TEXT("user32"));
        if (hUser32 == NULL)
            __leave;

        // Initialize INJDATA and then 
        // copy it to the remote process
        INJDATA DataLocal = {
            hWnd,
            MB_OK,
            (MESSAGEBOX) GetProcAddress(hUser32, "MessageBoxW")         
        };

        if( DataLocal.fnMessageBox == NULL )
            __leave;        

        wcscpy((LPWSTR) DataLocal.pbText, (LPCWSTR) pbString);
        wcscpy((LPWSTR) DataLocal.pbTextCap, (LPCWSTR) pbStringCap);

        // 1. Allocate memory in the remote process for INJDATA
        // 2. Write a copy of DataLocal to the allocated memory
        pDataRemote = (INJDATA*) VirtualAllocEx( hProcess, 0, sizeof(INJDATA), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );
        if (pDataRemote == NULL)
            __leave;
        WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, pDataRemote, &DataLocal, sizeof(INJDATA), &dwNumBytesXferred );


        // Calculate the number of bytes that ThreadFunc occupies
        const int cbCodeSize = ((LPBYTE) AfterThreadFunc - (LPBYTE) ThreadFunc);

        // 1. Allocate memory in the remote process for the injected ThreadFunc
        // 2. Write a copy of ThreadFunc to the allocated memory
        pCodeRemote = (PDWORD) VirtualAllocEx( hProcess, 0, cbCodeSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE );       
        if (pCodeRemote == NULL)
            __leave;
        WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, pCodeRemote, &ThreadFunc, cbCodeSize, &dwNumBytesXferred );


        // Start execution of remote ThreadFunc
        hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, 
                (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) pCodeRemote,
                pDataRemote, 0 , &dwThreadId);
        if (hThread == NULL)
            __leave;

        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

        }
    __finally {

        if ( pDataRemote != 0 )
            VirtualFreeEx( hProcess, pDataRemote, 0, MEM_RELEASE );

        if ( pCodeRemote != 0 )
            VirtualFreeEx( hProcess, pCodeRemote, 0, MEM_RELEASE );

        if ( hThread != NULL ) {
            GetExitCodeThread(hThread, (PDWORD) &nCharsXferred);
            CloseHandle(hThread);           
        }
    }

    // Return the number of chars retrieved 
    return nCharsXferred;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatelly this description is out of date. The newest versions of Windows have some protection called ASLR (Address space layout randomization). It protects them from basic code injection and ensures that each process has it's own address space. Not all processes has ASLR enabled but in most cases old technices won't fit.

Edit: Is the injected code executed and then you have crash? If so it's probably because the EIP register is incremented but there are no more instructions to execute in injected shellcode. You set the instruction pointer to the allocated memory and executed the code but after that process has merely no more valid instructions to execute. To prevent this I would allocate some more memory and write a simple shellcode which would simply loop infinitely and prevent EIP from executing some random things in memory.

Comment: yes, I try this in my virtul machine and winXP, but winmine crash when I close messageBox. I do not know Why.